# Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean

Tags: php, mysqli

I try to bind parameters to sql (mysqli) in php, but there is an error code as written above. 
This is the code I wrote:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO assignments (Classes_has_Subjects_classesHasSubjectsId, assignmentName, gradeForAssignment,protectiveGrade) 
                                  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
if ($stmt = false)
{
    echo "false";
}
else{
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $classesHasSubjectsId, $assignmentName, $gradeForAssignment,  $protectiveGrade);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

and here is the error message: 
11

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in

What's wrong?

Comment: missing one `s` OR `i` here `$stmt->bind_param("sss"`

Comment: `if ($stmt = false)` You're always setting `$stmt` on `false` here.

Comment: some teacher sad to write value before variable, like `if (false == $stmt)`, in comparisons so you will avoid those kind of errors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysqli\_fetch\_assoc() expects parameter / Call to a member function bind\_param() errors. How to get the actual mysql error and fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param)

Comment: I found myself searching for "bool" type on "bind_param" and the associated similar question has nothing in common. I vote to re-open. Please, remember that people looking for an answer search for the question, not by the answer they don't already know, in consequence, even if the related question eventually bring light on the topic, it is not a duplicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO assignments (Classes_has_Subjects_classesHasSubjectsId, assignmentName, gradeForAssignment,protectiveGrade) 
                                  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    if (!$stmt) {
        echo "false";
    }
    else {
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $classesHasSubjectsId, $assignmentName, $gradeForAssignment,  $protectiveGrade);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
```

`if ($stmt = false)` means you're assigning `false` to `$stmt`. Replace it with `if (!$stmt)`.

You're binding 4 parameters but only providing 3 types of values. I added a `s` in the `bind_param` function, assuming all your values are string. If some of the values are integers replace the corresponding `s` with an `i`. If there are doubles, replace with a `d`.

Are you sure the first field's name in the `assignments` table is `Classes_has_Subjects_classesHasSubjectsId`?